# MYSQL sum up values across two columns depending on values grouped from other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a network created MYSQL table with following fields:

```
IP_SRC, IP_DST, BYTES_IN, BYTES_OUT, START_TIME, STOP_TIME
1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 1080      540        1580684018  1580684100
8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 2000      4000       1580597618  1580597800
```

The TIME values are epoch time ticks and each record is basically one TCP session. IP addresses are stored as "int(10) unsigned" i.e. I use INET_NTOA to get to the "1.1.1.1" string. START_TIME, STOP_TIME, IN_BYTES and OUT_BYTES are also "int(10) unsigned"

I would like formulate a query (or procedure) to return a table with the following fields:

```
IP_ADDR, TotalOutBytes
1.1.1.1      12345
8.8.8.8      83747
8.8.4.4      2389
```

where for a given IP_ADDR say 1.1.1.1 the TotalOutBytes is the sum of IN_BYTES when IP_DST is 1.1.1.1 and OUT_BYTES when IP_SRC is 1.1.1.1. I would like all IP_SRC and IP_DST from the original table to be accounted for in the new table. I would also want this data to be collected for the last 24 hours.

Here's what I have that works for summing up just the IN_BYTES (and reporting as Mega Bytes in descending order for totals more than 50MB):

```
select IP_ADDR, format(MBx/1048576,0) AS TotalOutBytes from
  (select inet_ntoa(IP_DST_ADDR) AS IP_ADDR, sum(IN_BYTES) MBx from 
    (select IP_DST_ADDR, IN_BYTES from flowsv4 
        where FIRST_SWITCHED BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) total
GROUP BY IP_DST_ADDR) NEW WHERE MBx > 50*1048576 ORDER BY MBx DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` to create a derived table of `BYTES_IN` when an `IP_ADDR` is a destination and `BYTES_OUT` when `IP_ADDR` is a  source, and then `SUM` the bytes over that table:

```
SELECT IP_ADDR, SUM(BYTES) AS TotalOutBytes
FROM (
  SELECT IP_SRC AS IP_ADDR, BYTES_OUT AS BYTES
  FROM flowsv4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT IP_DST, BYTES_IN
  FROM flowsv4
) f
GROUP BY IP_ADDR
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/629761/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your existing query can le largely simplified by removing unecesary nesting.

To sum a different field according to the column that contains the concerned `ip`, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select 
    inet_ntoa(ip_dst_addr) as ip_addr, 
    format(
        sum(case '1.1.1.1'
            when ip_dst then in_bytes 
            when ip_src then out_bytes
        end) / 1048576,
        0
    ) totalBytes
from flowsv4 
where first_switched 
    between unix_timestamp(now() - interval 1 day) and unix_timestamp(now())
group by ip_dst_addr
having totalBytes > 50
order by totalBytes desc
```

Note that the sorting is a little less accurate the one in your original query since it uses the formated Mb value. If that really matters to you, then you can repeat the conditional `sum()` in the `order by` clause.